# For a Grails app to scale well, do you need to use EJBs?

Tags: mysql, grails, ejb, scalability

I've been working on a project in Grails and wondering if Enterprise Java Beans would be needed for it to scale on a [Tomcat Cloud Server](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-Hosting-td3808409.html).  I'm using basic GORM for persistence, and a mysql backend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, EJBs are not needed to scale.